# Code First Select Complex Types With Include()

Tags: entity-framework, include, code-first

Hierarchically i have 3 tables.
1 Classes table 
2 Student table 
3 Status table

Classes has students , Student has Status, as you guess. I'm trying to select fully  Classes object with Students property and Status properties of all Students.

My solution which is not working is below.

```
var query = Context.Classes.Include(x=> x.Student.Statu);
//result : query.Firts().Student.Statu = null
//I am get Statu
```

I have played so much with Include function ,I think I am missing somepoints.
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: I think complex types are always loaded (similar to primitive types), so no `Include` is needed.

Comment: Try `Context.Classes.Include(x=> x.Student.Select(y => y.Statu));`

Answer (score 2):

Your query should look like:

EF 6.0

> The path expression must be composed of simple property access expressions together with calls to Select in order to compose additional includes after including a collection property. Examples : [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Anchor_1).

```
 Context.Classes.Include(x=> x.Student.Select(y => y.Status));
```

EF Core

> You can drill down thru relationships to include multiple levels of related data using the ThenInclude method. The following example loads all blogs, their related posts, and the author of each post.
>   [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

```
Context.Classes.Include(x=> x.Student).ThenInclude(x => x.Status);
```